# Why the integral over the given function is complex?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

Suppose a function given by

```
CrossSections2t1approximated[Ss_, s2_, t1_, m_, m2_] := 
 1/(3 mW^4 Sqrt[s2] (s2 - Ss) Ss^(5/2) (s2 - t1)^4)
   128 g^2 \[Pi]^5 Sqrt[-t1] Sqrt[-s2 + Ss + t1]
   u^2 \[Alpha] (3 (8 s2^4 + 2 (Ss - 10 t1) s2^3 + 
       t1 (11 Ss + 14 t1) s2^2 + Ss (Ss - 19 t1) t1 s2 + 
       t1^2 (3 Ss^2 + 6 t1 Ss - 2 t1^2)) Log[(-m^2 + m2^2 + s2 - Sqrt[
        m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2]) /(-m^2 + m2^2 + s2 +
         Sqrt[m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2])] s2^2 + 
    Sqrt[m^4 - 2 (m2^2 + s2) m^2 + (m2^2 - s2)^2]
       s2 (30 s2^4 + (9 Ss - 51 t1) s2^3 + (3 Ss^2 + 47 t1 Ss - 
          6 t1^2) s2^2 + t1 (4 Ss^2 - 75 t1 Ss + 45 t1^2) s2 + 
       t1^2 (25 Ss^2 + 19 t1 Ss - 18 t1^2)))
```

You can see its explicit form on the picture: 
[image]

Here

$s_{2} - S_{s} \leqslant t_{1}\leqslant 0, \quad (m+m_{2})^{2} \leqslant s_{2} \leqslant S_{s},\quad 0< m_{2} < m,$

and therefore the function seems to be real on the whole domain of definition of these variables.

I want to evaluate the integral over $t_{1}$. The precise piece of code for the integration is given by

```
CrossSection[Ss_, s2_, m_, m2_] := 
 Simplify[Integrate[
   CrossSections2t1approximated[Ss, s2, t1, m, m2], {t1, t1lower, 
    t1upper}, 
   Assumptions -> 
    m > 0 && Ss > s2 && s2 > (m+m2)^2 && m2 > 0 && m2 < m ]]
```

After evaluation, it turns out that the integral is complex! The output is

```
(1/(3 mW^4 s2^(3/2) Ss^8 (s2-Ss)))8 \[Pi]^5 \[Alpha] g^2 u^2 (-4 s2^(3/2) Ss^5 Sqrt[m^4-2 m^2 (m2^2+s2)+(m2^2-s2)^2] (8 I (69 Sqrt[s2^5 Ss]-32 Sqrt[s2 Ss^5]+71 (s2 Ss)^(3/2)) log(Ss-s2)-4 I Sqrt[s2 Ss] (315 s2^2+178 s2 Ss+19 Ss^2) log(I Sqrt[Ss-s2])+\[Pi] (-591 Sqrt[s2^5 Ss]+73 s2^3-183 s2^2 Ss+109 Sqrt[s2 Ss^5]+159 s2 Ss^2-462 (s2 Ss)^(3/2)+31 Ss^3))-6 s2^(5/2) Ss^5 (4 I (7 Sqrt[s2^5 Ss]-19 Sqrt[s2 Ss^5]+52 (s2 Ss)^(3/2)) log(Ss-s2)+\[Pi] (-14 Sqrt[s2^5 Ss]+19 s2^3-87 s2^2 Ss+26 Sqrt[s2 Ss^5]+77 s2 Ss^2-188 (s2 Ss)^(3/2)+7 Ss^3)-48 I (Sqrt[s2 Ss^5]+7 (s2 Ss)^(3/2)) log(I Sqrt[Ss-s2])) log((-m^2-Sqrt[m^4-2 m^2 (m2^2+s2)+(m2^2-s2)^2]+m2^2+s2)/(-m^2+Sqrt[m^4-2 m^2 (m2^2+s2)+(m2^2-s2)^2]+m2^2+s2)))
```

The precise form of the integtal is given on the picture:
[image]

What is the reason for this? Sorry for this strange question.

Comment: 1. Nobody here has the patience to retype such an elaborate integrand. Please copy it as an `InputForm[]` expression, and paste it in your question. 2. Do not use the [tag:bugs] tag until other users have confirmed your observations.

Comment: @J.M. I've corrected the question.

Comment: When I specify the limits of integration as `s2-Ss` to zero instead of  `t1lower` and `t1upper`, I get a real result.  What limits of integration are you using?

Comment: @LouisB : they are given in the form
t1lower = -1/(2*Ss)*(Ss*(Ss - s2) + 
     Sqrt[lambda[Ss, 0, 0]*lambda[Ss, s2, 0]]);
t1upper = -1/(2*Ss)*(Ss*(Ss - s2) - 
     Sqrt[lambda[Ss, 0, 0]*lambda[Ss, s2, 0]]),

where 

lambda[a,b,c] := a^2+b^2+c^2-2*(a*b+b*c+a*c)

In my case of arguments of lambda the limits of the integration should reduce to $-Ss-s2, 0$.

Comment: @LouisB : thank you! It seems that the problem was in incorrect interpretation of $\sqrt{(a-b)^{2}}$ in my definition of integration limits.